# ReactJS, axios response is not being sent to my dataSet properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, axios

i've been grinding my brain how to fix this. I have a DataTable component that displays a dataSet from axios response (from parent - ProductListing).

I can get the expected result from axios but only after the DataTable is already rendered, I know im just missing something, hope someone can help me.

ProductListing component

```
class ProductListings extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataSet: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getProducts({}).then(
      (res) => {
        this.setState({ dataSet: res.data });
      }
    );
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.dataSet);
    return (
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <section className="content-header">
          <DataTable dataSet={this.state.dataSet}/>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(null, {getProducts})(ProductListings);
```

DataTable component

```
class DataTable extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.DataTable(
      {
        data: this.props.dataSet,
        columns: [
          { title: "ID" },
          { title: "Title" },
          { title: "Short Desc" },
          { title: "Full Desc" },
          { title: "Release Type" },
          { title: "Country Code" }
        ],
        buttons: [
          'copy'
        ]
      }
    )
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="display" width="100%" ref={el => this.el = el}></table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DataTable;
```

[Console log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BktPN.png)
[Console log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVFtv.png)

Comment: Can you try adding constructor to your child component(DataTable) like below
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I see no issues with the code.

Do you want to display `DataTable` only when response is ready?

Comment: By the time the `DataTable` component mounts, `this.props.dataSet` is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are no issues with your code and this is expected behavior. 
You are calling asynchronous request in the `ProductsListing` thus it can't be guaranteed that data comes before child is being rendered. By the time when your `DataTable` is mounted, request is not finished thats why you're getting an empty(initial) array.

If you want to render `DataTable` component only when data is ready - do check for array length in the `ProductsListing` component.

Like this:

```
class ProductListings extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataSet: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getProducts({}).then(
      (res) => {
        this.setState({ dataSet: res.data });
      }
    );
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.dataSet);
    return (
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <section className="content-header">
          {!!this.state.dataSet.length && <DataTable dataSet={this.state.dataSet}/>}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(null, {getProducts})(ProductListings);
```

In this case you can be sure that your `DataTable` will be rendered after response is ready.

Here is one **pitfall**. Your component won't be rendered if array is empty even if server returns so.

If you want to display something like "data is empty" in your table and get your code working as you want use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook instead of `componentDidMount` in `DataTable` component.

Comment: I knew it, this was just a simple fix and im just missing something. Thanks